# WPF Listbox Items Won't Display

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox

I have a class called `Products` with a property called `Name`. I'm trying to bind a list of `Products` to a ListBox named `disp_products` and then display the each `Name` in `disp_products`.
The binding works fine, but when I run the code, blank items are put in `disp_products`.

[Here's what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbx5q.png)

This is what I have got for the XAML.

```
<ListBox x:Name="disp_products">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

And here's the C# code:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ObservableCollection<Product> prods = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
        prods.Add(new Product(1, "Product Name 1", 33.2, 1));
        prods.Add(new Product(2, "Product Name 2", 12.1, 1));
        disp_products.ItemsSource = prods;
    }
```

What I want are entries "Product Name 1" and "Product Name 2" displayed in the `ListBox` `disp_products`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: When only want to show one property then just use the `DisplayMemberPath` instead of setting the `ItemTemplate`. `<ListBox x:Name="disp_products" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />`. I assume your `Product` class does have a property called `Name`

Comment: Make sure that `Name` is actually a public property, not a field. You should observe any data binding error messages in the Output Window in Visual Studio when you debug your application.

Comment: hi man , i really don't understand the answer if you can explain, please! thank you